# Is it possible to "lock" a session in Laravel 5.8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to implement a "lock window" function into my application. Is it possible to lock a session and reactivate it?

*Case:* After x minutes the application will get locked. The user must now type in his password and will be redirected to the former route and logged in again.

Answer (score 1):

In /config/session.php you can set the amount of idle time before the session expires:

```
   /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 120, // edit this
```

If you want to include non idle time, you can create some middleware which can auto log-out your user. You can store the time the user logged-in in the session, and in the middleware store your `$timeout` variable. You can force log-out of an auth user like so:

`auth()->logout()`

if the time logged in + `$timeout` has passed.